# Comparing two variables to certain decimal place during while loop?

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, while-loop

If you take a look at the code below you can see that I am running an if statement to check whether or not a text field is empty, if it is empty it runs the while loop. My question is when I am comparing the the two Variables, Q and Qc I only want to test the loop to a certain decimal place for example the tenths place.

I tried using @"%.1f" along with the variable but I am guessing my syntax is wrong. If someone could help me I would appreciate it.

```
        if ([heightTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
            while (Q != Qc) {
                Hc = Hc + 0.01;
                Qc = 1.486*(Hc*W)*(powf(((Hc*W)/(2*Hc+2*W)), 0.6666666667))*(powf(S, 0.50))/n;
                H = Hc;
            }
        }
        if ([widthTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
            while (Q != Qc) {
                Wc = Wc + 0.01;
                Qc = 1.486*(H*Wc)*(powf(((H*Wc)/(2*H+2*Wc)), 0.6666666667))*(powf(S, 0.50))/n;
                W = Wc;
            }
        }
```

Thanks,
Dana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be an easier way to go about this, but off hand, this would be the approach I would take.

First off, and this may not apply to you, but I've had issues comparing a textField to @"" (where it would never say this is true), so I had since used `if ([myTextField.text length])` instead.

As for the comparison, this is the code I would use:

```
NSString *qString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", Q];
NSString *qcString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", Qc];
while (![qString isEqualToString:qcString]) {
    // continue code to update Qc...;
    // update qcString;
    qcString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", Qc];
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, I came up with a solution that works best for what I want to do, Instead of checking for equality I just run the while loop while Qc is less that Q.

Comment: You response is helpful and I am sure I can use it in the future.

Comment: I'm certainly glad to have helped, though it's great to hear you came up with your own solution.  It's always a good feeling to come up with answers to your own questions

Answer (score 1):

Here's a thought: 
If you want to compare to one digit past the decimal point first multiply the number by 10.  Then you have the option to use roundf, floor, ceil or other operations to shape the number.  When done you can divide by 10 again and make your comparison.

Comment: Exactly. Simply use `round(10 * num) / 10;` and 1.5443252452345 will turn into 1.50000000000.

Answer (score 0):

To test to greater than 0.1 difference, use this:

```
while (fabs(Q - Qc) > .1) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: You response is helpful and I am sure I can use it in the future. Thanks. This is a really clean solution, I wish I could accept both answers. I am new so I can't give you rep points just yet.